# MVC 4 validation integer overflow

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a property on my viewmodel of type `int?`

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents A company Id 
/// </summary>
[Range(1, 999999999, ErrorMessage="Error"])          
public int? CompanyId{ get; set; }
```

From the textbox I user enter a big number that overflows `int32` maxValue, then I think 
an internal validation exception is thrown but the message doesn't appear.

I am overriding default messages in `global.asax` by calling:

```
DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey = "GlobalResources";
```

Do you know what key I should enter to override resources so that the message will appear? Is there any specific message for `Int32` overflow?

I've overridden the `PropertyValueInvalid` but it doesn't show. It seems like there is another key that need to be overridden. Please point me where can I find all list of default keys.

Comment: Do you want to show the message on your `View`? If so, can you post the code for the `View`?

Comment: I cant now since I am not near pc , but I have @Html.ValidationSummary() inside BeginForm if this was the question.

Comment: Do you also have a `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CompanyId)` on your `View`?

Comment: No , only Validation summary

Comment: Without it, a validation message for that particular property won't show up. However, the summary should still show up. Is that the case?

Comment: It doesn't appears in summary too , only textbox bacome with red border

Comment: It is not suppose to appear in the summary. But the fact that the box becomes red is enough to understand it is not working because you are missing that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CompanyId)` to your view so the validation message actually shows. Otherwise you will only get a `red` border on your textbox, as you mentioned.